# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular

I'm early beginning in Angular2 and find annoying error, in console I have got this error

> onError: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Here is my code for book.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Book } from './book';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BookService{
    books:Array<Book>;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getBooks() {
        return this._http.get('/api/books')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

And my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { BookService } from './book.service';
import { Book } from './book';
import {BooksFilterPipe} from './book.filter';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/book.component.html',
    providers: [BookService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    pipes: [BooksFilterPipe]
})

export class AppComponent{
    books:Array<Book>;

    constructor(private _bookService: BookService) { }

    getBooks() {
        this._bookService
            .getBooks()
            .subscribe(
                books => this.books = books,
                error => console.log('onError: %s', error)
            );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBooks();
    }
}
```

And my ApiController (routing is fine)

```
<?php

namespace Books\Controller;

use Bootstrap\App;

class ApiController extends App{
    public function getBooksAction(){
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $books = $em->getRepository('Books\Model\Books')->findAll();

        $newBooks = [];

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            $newBooks[] = $book->toArray();
        }

        return $this->renderAjax($newBooks);
    }
}
```

Here is my console log for command

> console.log(this._bookService.getBooks());

[screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OJx6.png)

Help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to examine the actual content of the HTTP response. It's probably HTML (an error report) instead of JSON.

Comment: The JSON has an illegal character. Can you provide the JSON data?